# Expected Number of points in Point Poisson Process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, expectation

Let $\lambda$ be the intensity of points, distributed as point poisson process, in a square grid of area $A$. Then, the Cumulative disributive function is given by:
$$
P(r \leq R) = 1 - e^{-\lambda \pi R^2}
$$
Using the above cumulative distributive function, how can i calculate the expected number of points, how can i calculate the expected number of points within a radius $R$.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Comment: My friend, the concept didn't work.
Basically, the problem was that there are two things to do: \\
1. I want to distribute point using Point Poisson Process in s square area. \\
2. After that, there is another random process in which M numbers are selected from {1,2,.., L} and places randomly on the points, selected in step 1. So, for each point in the space, there are M points assigned to it.
So, the problem was how to calculate the density of each number over a given circle of radius R?

Comment: "So, for each point in the space, there are M points assigned to it" ?? Well... When you will be decided to communicate with others, just call me, unfortunately at present you are mainly talking to yourself. One thing is certain though, which is that the setting you describe in your comment is NOT in the question hence to disqualify already posted answers for the reason that they would not answer this quite different question is not a behaviour one can accept.

Comment: My friend, i told you the whole problem, which i am going to resolve. In the posted question, i only mentioned the first part which is enough to move forward.

Comment: And which was completely answered. So what is the point of making this whole page go astray by flouting the rules of the site?

Comment: Your behavior is very bad. Please, i didn't ask anything on this forum. You asked whether i got something from answers or not. In response to your comment, i posted about the problem in detail. Therefore, i didn't violate any rules. So, please if you don't like my posts, then don't comment.

Comment: You did ask a question on this "forum" and you do flout the rules of the site. One of the rules is that when an answer addresses the question as it is asked, one may accept it, instead you started adding unclear and unrelated considerations in comments, as if the site was a chat service. Which behaviour is that?

Comment: What do you mean by accepting? Let me know how to do it.
I am new to this forum and therefore, i am not aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for telling. I will do that in future.

Answer (score 1):

The number of points of a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ which are in a domain $D$ of volume $V$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda V$. Hence its expectation is $_____$.

(As explained in every decent introduction to Poisson processes.)

**Nota:** I am unable to ascribe a meaning to this passage from the question:

*Then, the Cumulative disributive function is given by:
$
P(r \leq R) = 1 - e^{-\lambda \pi R^2}
$
Using the above cumulative distributive function...*

Comment: I couldn't read the expectation value.

Comment: You are studying Poisson *processes* but you are unable to find the expectation of a Poisson *random variable* with known parameter?

Comment: Yes, i am studying poisson processes but unable to find expectation. Thats why, i posted the question on this forum.

Comment: Sorry but to ask a question about Poisson **processes** when one lacks the basics of Poisson **random variables** is odd, to say the least. Anyway, what about checking [the obvious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)?

Comment: my Friend, I read all these things before. I know about poisson process. I know about point processes. I read all the things. I understand them from analytical perspective. When i perform simulations, it doesn't turn out to be the case because i have to do some kind of conditional expectation to find the number of points within a region.

Comment: ?? If you had read the link, even cursorily, you would know the expectation of a Poisson random variable with given parameter.